# Export a PowerShell output

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have to export my output in an Excel file as csv to update my datas after running the query. Problem: it does nothing

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = [ordered]@{}
$columns = foreach ($i in 0..7) { ,[Collections.ArrayList]@() }

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $value = $row.Column1
    $ref[$value] = $true
    $columns[0].add($value) >$null
}

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $i = 1
    foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
        $value = $row.$col
        if (!$ref[$value]) {
            $columns[$i].add($value) >$null
        }
        $i++
    }
}

$maxLine = ($columns | select -expand Count | measure -Maximum).Maximum - 1
$csv = foreach ($i in 0..$maxLine) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Column1 = $columns[0][$i]
        Column2 = $columns[1][$i]
        Column3 = $columns[2][$i]
        Column4 = $columns[3][$i]

    }
}


$csv | Format-Table
```

The code allows to remove matching cells

Comment: Output of what? Please include the initial script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$csv | Format-Table` with

```
$csv | Export-CSV -Path "C:\folder\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I have to enter an InputObject, what shall I do ?

Comment: you're piping your input object to it, see edited answer.